# Downloading linux mint through tor

Tags: tails, linux

I have just got a pre owned computer that has been wiped. I'm really wanting to put Linux mint on it as the OS.

I have a tails usb that I use to access tor and was wondering if anyone knows how I can burn Linux mint to a separate usb through tor. I really don't want to have to download windows.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to do this.

---

1. Start up Tails on your PC
2. Download the desired ISO
3. Install software to create a bootable USB stick (e.g. `unetbootin`) 
   (See: https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/additional_software/index.en.html)
4. Plug in second USB drive and "burn" the ISO on it... or real burning on a DVD with the preinstalled `brasero` is also possible (if you've got a DVD-drive).